# Support reaction on rotating object

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

[image: Rod about to rotate]

If I cut the thread holding the rod (see image), what will be the vertical support reactions immediately after? I can't for the life of me get my head around this. Apparently it is $ mg - V = ma_t$ where $a_t$ is the tangential acceleration.

I've spent several hours trying to understand, and maybe it's the fact that I've spent the past several days studying for hours and hours and my brain is really numb right now, but I just don't get it. I'm not simply asking for you guys to do the work for me. I really need to understand what's going on here.

Comment: Could you clarify exactly what "the vertical support reactions" means?  And what does that arrow with the "v" mean?  Is the vertical support moving upwards with velocity v?

Comment: v is the upwards support reaction from the hinge. It's stationary. Sorry for not clarifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to approach a problem like this is to go through a formulaic process every time. Let me suggest the following steps.

1. Identify the system for which we want to write down the dynamics (defining the system will allow us to distinguish "internal" and "external" forces on the system).
2. Write down the governing equation, in this case $d\vec{p}/dt = \vec{F}_\text{net,ext}$; the time derivative of momentum (which equals $m a$ whenever the mass is constant in time) equals the net external force on the system.
3. Rearrange this equation.

For instance, let's identify the rod as the system. What are the external forces acting on the rod? They are: gravity ($m g$), the hinge (is that the vertical support $V$ you're talking about? I'll assume it is), and a tension force $T$ from the string. Before the string is cut, we know that nothing is moving, so $dp/dt = m a = 0$. Therefore the net external forces must sum to zero as well: $\vec{V} + \vec{T} - m g \hat{y} = 0$. Since all forces are along the y-axis, we can simply extract that component from the vector equation I wrote down and say that $V + T - m g = m a = 0$.

Now, when you cut the string, the tension force will go away, and $m a$ will no longer be zero. I'll leave you to figure out how this translates into your "apparent" answer, with two warnings:

1. Make sure to pay attention to what the signs mean, and what direction is "tangential".
2. The analysis I've provided above is only useful *at the instant* that the cord is cut. It's always *valid*, but not always useful, because the rod really can't be regarded as a point particle. As soon as the rod is no longer vertical, you will need to appeal to a the angular momentum equation $d\vec{L}/dt = \vec{\tau}_\text{net,ext}$ instead. If you haven't studied torque and angular momentum yet, then you can probably safely ignore this and just treat it as I did above.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for providing such an elaborate answer. For translational motion, mg - V = ma makes a lot of sense to me. I just get so confused when we throw rotations into the equation. I'm struggling with the intuition.

Comment: First of all, don't bother trying to use $F=ma$ to deal with rotational motion; as I mentioned, there's an entirely separate conceptual apparatus for that using torque and angular momentum. Those concepts can and should be understood as capturing the $F=ma$ dynamics of every individual atom in the rotatin object, but they provide a much more intuitive formulation for computing the results. This is why the problem you presented (presumably) asked for the force *at the instant* the rope was cut; once the rod rotates, you need new physics to deal with it.

Answer (score 1):

What is the force on *O* in order to keep the pivot fixed in space. In these problem follow these steps:

1. Vertical Velocity Kinematics of the center of mass $\dot{y}_C = \dot{y}_O + \frac{L}{2} \omega$
2. Vertical Acceleration Kinematics of the center of mass $\ddot{y}_C = \ddot{y}_O +\frac{L}{2} \dot{\omega}$
3. Sum of forces change in linear momentum $F_O-m g = m \ddot{y}_C$
4. Sum of moments about the center of mass equal change in angular momentum $-\frac{L}{2} F_O = I_C \dot{\omega}$ where $I_C=\frac{m L^2}{12}$ is the mass moment of inertia.
5. Constrain the pivot with $\ddot{y}_O=\dot{y}_O=0$ and thus $\ddot{y}_C =\frac{L}{2}\dot{\omega}$
6. The equations of motion are $$\begin{aligned} F_O&=m \left( \frac{L}{2} \dot{\omega}+g \right) \\ -\frac{L}{2} F_O &= I_C \dot{\omega} \end{aligned}$$
7. Solve the above system of two equations for the force at the pivot $F_O$ and the angular acceleration $\dot{\omega}$.

> You will find $F_O = \frac{1}{4} m g$